# error al insertar

Tags: c#, ajax, .net-6.0

tengo una web api en net6 y lo consumo con ajax, el problema radica que me esta generando un error al enviar un dato, me imagino que le falta algo, pero no he podido dar con eso.

este es mi modelo en C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace API_Mangoo.Model
{
    public class Estructura
    {
        public int idestructura { get; set; }
        public Byte[] estructura { get; set; }
        public int idplanta { get; set; }
    }
}
```

en estructura voy a almacenar el html obtenido dentro de un div, en mysql lo tengo para almarcenar en un longblob

y este es mi ajax

```
var divarquitectura = $('#creadorarquitecturadiv')[0]['innerHTML'];
var settings = {
            "url": "https://localhost:7265/api/Estructura/Insertar",
            "method": "POST",
            "timeout": 0,
            "headers": {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "data": JSON.stringify({
                "estructura": divarquitectura,
                "idplanta": $('#selectplanta').val()
            }),
        };
        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            recargar();
        });
```

y me genera este error

```
{type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",…}
errors
: 
{estructura: ["The estructura field is required."], $.estructura: [,…]}
status
: 
400
title
: 
"One or more validation errors occurred."
traceId
: 
"00-43f9b9dcd0ad1ecf5ad2c381cad56207-c55725038f186470-00"
type
: 
"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
```

y si cambio el campo estructura por string si me deja almacenar sin problema, pero al momento de consultar eso, me sale este error

```
System.Data.DataException: Error parsing column 1 (estructura=System.Byte[] - Object)
```

la verdad no se por donde irme, si seguir con el string o cambiarlo a byte

Comment: ¿Entiendes la diferencia entre un byte, un byte[] y un string? Para ayudarte mejor, ¿podrías colocar el objetivo de `estructura` y qué representa por favor?

Comment: El HTML es un string, por lo que debes seguir por ahí

Comment: el objetivo de estructura es almacenar todo el codigo o etiquetas que se encuentra dentro de un DIV